# Opencv module of matlab cannot work right

Tags: matlab, opencv, image-processing

I have download the newest version of Opencv which contain module of Matlab,most of the opencv API work in matlab,the question is when I want to draw a line or circle in Matlab with opencv API,it does not work.

I use it in matlab like follows:

```
    output=cv.line(input,[0 0],[100 100],[255 0 0]);
```

but it does not work,in help,the function can be called as:

```
    output=cv.line(input,point1,point2,Color,[some default options)
```

I have checked the opencv source code,but still do not get the answer,can the Color be presented by [x y z],from matlab to opencv?
Is there anyone who knows how to use the  API?

Comment: Could you clarify "does not work"? What is the observed behavior, what is the error message you see, or how does the result not fit your expectation?

Answer (score 0):

Can you clarify how exactly it doesn't work? Is there an error message? Does it crash? Does it produce any output at all?

Without knowing any of that, my guess would be that your problem has to with the data types of the images. Check whether or not the input is an RGB image. Check what its class (data type) is. If it is double or single, try using [1 0 0] for the color instead of [255 0 0].

Also, if you have the Computer Vision System Toolbox, you can use [insertShape](http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/insertshape.html) to draw lines, polygons, and circles into images..